# React Native Stream MJPEG Video

Tags: javascript, react-native, video

Estoy en un proyecto y necesito enviar lo que ve mi cámara a mi computadora. Primero intente con **RTMP** y conseguí poder enviar el vídeo pero la latencia era extremadamente alta (dando un delay de 5 a 8 seg) Lamentablemente para que el proyecto funcione correctamente necesitaría que el delay que pueda tener sea menor a 1 segundo.

Ante esto se me ocurrió utilizar **MJPEG** con algún protocolo **web** para enviarlo a la computadora (Donde podría ejecutar algún server como lo hice con el **RTMP**)

Esto lo estoy haciendo manteniendo los 2 equipos conectados a la misma red WiFi de 5GHz para tener estabilidad en la transferencia.

Cualquier duda o consulta estoy a su disposición y desde ya muchas gracias por toda la colaboración.

Comment: ¿Probaste WebRTC? Si no, puedes comenzar con [WebRTC Experiment](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/) o con [react native WebRTC](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc) para ver si alguna opción te sirve.

Comment: Hola @Triby antes que nada gracias por pasarte. Intente implementar React Native WebRTC y la app se cierra sin dejar log o informacion. Adicionalmente a esto WebRTC disminuye la calidad del video